# Ignore case in Entity Framework 6 after migrating from SQL Server to PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We have migrated the database schema manually from SQL Server to PostgreSQL as we are using the database first approach.

But the problem we are facing now is, that the table and column names are all lower case vs. Pascal case in the SQL Server and the entities in EF/application.
Because of this, EF doesn't recognize any entities.

We would like to keep the cases in the code as Pascal case is the standard in C#.

Is there a database first approach to ignore the case (possible in EF-Core but not EF6) or any other solution?
And if there is none, how hard is it to switch to the code first approach?

Comment: In ef-core-6 you can use [model-based conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/conventions/model).

Comment: This is for the code first approach. we would like to stay on database first

Comment: That's OK, in that case it basically only tells EF how to generate SQL.

Comment: @GertArnold the question is not about EF Core